# Android Maskfilter degrading performance over a long time

Tags: android, performance

I have a problem with my drawing app, in that the mask filters are using a lot of paramaters and lisiting it in to the array list. I think everytime I draw the maskfilter gets added to the arraylist and then the canvas draws the whole array list from scratch. Or it is the problem with `onDraw` please give me suggestions for performance improvements.

```
public class PaintingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PaintView paintView;
    private Toolbar mTopToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paint);

        mTopToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mTopToolbar);
        paintView = (PaintView) findViewById(R.id.paintView);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        paintView.init(metrics);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.draw_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void colorPicker() {

            final Context context = PaintingActivity.this;

        ColorPickerDialogBuilder
                .with(context)
                .setTitle("Choose color")
                .initialColor(DEFAULT_COLOR)
                .wheelType(ColorPickerView.WHEEL_TYPE.CIRCLE)
                .density(12)
                .setOnColorSelectedListener(new OnColorSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onColorSelected(int selectedColor) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "onColorSelected: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(selectedColor), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new ColorPickerClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedColor, Integer[] allColors) {
                        //changeBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                })
                .build()
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.normal:
                paintView.normal();
                return true;

            case R.id.emboss:
                paintView.emboss();
                return true;

            case R.id.blur:
                paintView.blur();
                return true;

            case R.id.color_picker:
                colorPicker();
                return true;

            case R.id.clear:
                paintView.clear();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Then my PaintView

```
public class PaintView extends View {

    public static int BRUSH_SIZE = 20;
    public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.RED;
    public static final int DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    private float mX, mY;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private ArrayList<FingerPath> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    private int currentColor;
    private int backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
    private int strokeWidth;
    private boolean emboss;
    private boolean blur;
    private MaskFilter mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter mBlur;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    public PaintView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);

    }

    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xff);

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] {1, 1, 1}, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(5, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics) {
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
        strokeWidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
    }

    public void normal() {
        emboss = false;
        blur = false;
    }

    public void emboss() {
        emboss = true;
        blur = false;
    }

    public void blur() {
        emboss = false;
        blur = true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
        paths.clear();
        normal();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

        for (FingerPath fp : paths) {
            mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);

            if (fp.emboss)
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
            else if (fp.blur)
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);

            mCanvas.drawPath(fp.path, mPaint);

        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        mPath = new Path();
        FingerPath fp = new FingerPath(currentColor, emboss, blur, strokeWidth, mPath);
        paths.add(fp);

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);

        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touchUp() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                touchStart(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                touchMove(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                touchUp();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Also my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lolow.asserty.asserty.paint.PaintingActivity"
    android:background="@color/lightGrey">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.lolow.asserty.asserty.paint.PaintView
            android:id="@+id/paintView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/paint_view_border"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is also my **path** class:

```
public class FingerPath {
    public int color;
    public boolean emboss;
    public boolean blur;
    public int strokeWidth;
    public Path path;

    public FingerPath(int color, boolean emboss, boolean blur, int strokeWidth, Path path) {
        this.color = color;
        this.emboss = emboss;
        this.blur = blur;
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

Comment: how many iterations do you have in `for (FingerPath fp : paths) {` loop?

Comment: It goes on how many paths the user has drawn.

Comment: so how many iterations do you have? also, why that loop is executed inside `onDraw` method? all your drawings are done on off-screen `mBitmap` which is never cleared after all - instead you can draw your bitmap when needed - something like [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/11e58d52f8d5e48409c5580252ec5326/raw/a2e2a3362fcc75a5867a90a28181c2286d9f733e/TouchPaint.java)

Comment: Thank you just what I needed